# Is it legal for an employer to implant chips in the body of employees?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, medical

It is being reported in the media that [employers in the UK are planning to microchip employees](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2018/11/10/major-uk-companies-preparing-microchip-employees/?li_source=LI&li_medium=li-recommendation-widget).

Can such a procedure be legal?

A qualified medical professional would only be allowed to perform the procedure on someone who has given informed and freely-given consent, which cannot presumably be given if the consequence of refusing is to suffer penalties at work.

If it's not performed by a qualified medical professional, then wouldn't they be guilty of common assault? The only defence I can see against a charge of assault would be consent, and again, consent cannot be said to be freely given.

Comment: It seems to me that a court could easily find that consent could be given freely even in the context of an employer-employee relationship, because the employee is free to end the relationship and get a job elsewhere.

Comment: The UK is very unlikely to see that as remotely conscionable. The USA attitude that "it's a free world, anybody can find any job any time" doesn't tend to hold in the Commonwealth.

Comment: I would think it would depend on what incentives the employer offered.  If it was "agree or be fired", that's not much in the way of consent.  If it was "here's some ways we can make your job easier if you get chipped", it may well be valid consent.